# was unable to load a nib named

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, crash-reports

I just released my new App iBeat, which worked fine for me and my friends before release.

Now appearently many customers get the same crash, that is always happening at a similar stage.

Here's a (symbolicated) sample crash-report:

```
Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x30d7c2d4
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception \'NSInternalInconsistencyException\', reason: \'Could not load NIB in bundle: \'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/5BBE8B5E-ECF5-4CA8-97A6-1F5BF8AC7792/iBeat.app> (loaded)\' with name \'SettingsVC_iPad\'\'

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x000792d4 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x000792bd raise + 17
2   iBeat                               0x0003f301 uncaught_exception_handler (PLCrashReporter.m:137)
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000a0adf __handleUncaughtException + 239
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00006593 _objc_terminate + 103
5   libstdc++.6.dylib                   0x00042df9 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 53
6   libstdc++.6.dylib                   0x00042e4d std::terminate() + 17
7   libstdc++.6.dylib                   0x00042f1d __cxa_throw + 85
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000054cb objc_exception_throw + 71
9   CoreFoundation                      0x000a07c9 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 69
10  CoreFoundation                      0x000a0803 +[NSException raise:format:] + 35
11  UIKit                               0x001e9783 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1111
12  UIKit                               0x001eab39 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 93
13  UIKit                               0x0013e8e5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 37
14  UIKit                               0x0013dcb9 -[UIViewController loadView] + 81
15  UIKit                               0x0003e227 -[UIViewController view] + 31
16  UIKit                               0x0004ad0b -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 23
17  UIKit                               0x0004ab7b -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 31
18  UIKit                               0x0004aa79 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 25
19  UIKit                               0x0004a551 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 381
20  UIKit                               0x0004a35f -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 183
21  UIKit                               0x0004a2a3 -[UINavigationController viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 15
22  UIKit                               0x0004a23f -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 139
23  UIKit                               0x000130cf -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 27
24  CoreFoundation                      0x0003ebbf -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 23
25  QuartzCore                          0x0000f685 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 121
26  QuartzCore                          0x0000f43d CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 185
27  QuartzCore                          0x0000f377 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 79
28  UIKit                               0x0008c48f -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutIfNeeded] + 23
29  UIKit                               0x000d0ec1 -[UIViewController window:willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:] + 357
30  UIKit                               0x00110e49 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 3101
31  UIKit                               0x000cf6db -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 679
32  UIKit                               0x000cefc7 -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:withTransition:] + 2139
33  UIKit                               0x000ce6a3 -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 59
34  iBeat                               0x000044f3 -[MetronomeVC settingsTapped] (MetronomeVC.m:956)
```

This crash happens across all supported iOS versions, with different nib-files, that is with SettingsVC_iPad, InfoVC_iPhone or Settings_VC_iPhone.

The problem is, I can't recreate this error, not on my iPod, neither on my iPad.

Any suggestions? (This crash seems to be really common, I already got 200 crashreports on this)

EDIT: To clarify, I did experiment with the downloaded version from the App Store, so I tried to recreate it with the exact version the errors happened with.

Comment: Can you recreate the error if you download the app from the app store? It might be an issue with the iOS version at play.

Comment: could it be a low memory crash?  Try opening a bunch of stuff then open your app and see if you can recreate the crash.

Comment: What's the name of your nib file?

Comment: The Name of the nib-file is "InfoVC_iPhone.xib", it has a german and an english version, but I tested switching my iPad into both german and english, still can't recreate the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience, but it was totally my fault.

Really early in the development I was planning to do a french version, so I had an fr.lproj folder that I never deleted. Appearently the App was still looking for french versions of my IB files there, when started in french.

"On n'a jamais fini d'apprendre."

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it solves ur problem or not .. but I strongly doubt that this is the mistake ...

I think when u packaged ur application , u didn't copy ur nib file into ur project and has only a reference there..

You are not getting this error because probably you are taking your app from your development mac and the nib file's reference is present there ..

Delete the app from ur iphone and Try downloading the app from app store and then see ..

Comment: Unfortunately I did exactly that, because that was my first guess too. I deleted the App from my iPad and iTunes, downloaded it from the store and synced with iTunes. After that I couldn't recreate the error and was stuck. Thats why I had to ask here.